# How to draw scrollbars on WPF Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, scrollbars

I am trying to create a canvas with scroll bars.
Can anyone help me give some ideas on how to do this?
I have already tried using grid of 1 row and 1 column but due to certain constraints I want to use canvas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could put the canvas inside of a scrollviewer.  I tried this quick test and it allowed me to scroll through the contents of the canvas.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100" Width="200">
    <Canvas Height="400" Width="400">
            //Content here
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

edit:  Here is an example where the scroll-bars show up only when needed, and it changes dynamically as the canvas size changes.

```
    <Button Content="Change Canvas Size" Click="ChangeCanvasSize_Click"/>
<ScrollViewer Height="100" Width="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas x:Name="TestCanvas">
            <TextBlock Text="Test Test"/>
    </Canvas>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Changing canvas size with button click:

```
    private void ChangeCanvasSize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestCanvas.Width = 600;
        TestCanvas.Height = 600;
    }
```

In this example, I start out with no scroll-bars and when I click the button to expand the canvas, scroll-bars appear.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the thing is I do not know the size of my canvas until runtime. So can not have a fixed size canvas.
I will increase the dimension of canvas if user, say, clicks near the boundary of existing canvas then the canvas width and/or height will increase by say 50 units and scrollbar should appear.

Comment: This should still work, if you set the visibility of the scroll-bars to "Auto".  I modified my example to illustrate.

Answer (score 3):

Ok after working with it for sometime I figured out a way. Create a XAML like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
 <Grid x:Name="drawingGrid" SizeChanged="drawingGrid_SizeChanged">
<Canvas Name="drawingCanvas"> /<Canvas>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

On windowLoad function set the canvas height/width equal to grid height/width. Update the canvas ht/wd:

1. when grid size changes, due to mininmize/maximize.
2. dragging an element beyond the boundaries of canvas or creating a new element too close the edge of canvas

   ```
   double dHeight = 220;
   if (drawingCanvas.Height < CurrentPosition.Y + dHeight)
   {
       // increase canvas height
       drawingCanvas.Height += (2 * dHeight);
   }
   ```

Hope this is of some help. Please share if anyone has any better idea or suggestions to improve this.

Answer (score 2):

By combining Mario-sannum's answer and your question then I've made a solution that should work fine in most cases..

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid x:Name="drawingGrid" SizeChanged="drawingGrid_SizeChanged">
<Canvas Name="c">
<TextBlock x:Name="draw_Text" Text="Test Test"/>
</<Canvas>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>


void drawingGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
      try { c.Height = draw_Text.ActualHeight; } catch { }
      try { c.Width = draw_Text.ActualWidth; } catch { }
}
```

That should resize the Canvas so the scrollviewer can scroll...